# PHP Symfony: Undefined type 'Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver'

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I was just about to create a new Form with Symfony: `php bin/console make:Form`

It created a new form, however, I got an error:

```
Undefined type 'Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver'.
```

This is the component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

OptionsResolver is snake-underlined did something change in imports? I use lates Symfony version

Comment: what is the symfony version are you using ?

Comment: I have `Symfony 5.2.0 (env: dev, debug: true)`

Comment: does the dep **symfony/options-resolver** already installed ?

Comment: yup I already installed it aditionally... but I have lots more problems of the same kind.. but none of it seems to matter, my app works still fine, just wondering..